# byte[] to BitmapImage conversion fails

Tags: c#, wpf, image, bitmapimage

I have a problem. I want to convert `BitmapImage` into `byte[]` array and back.

I wrote these methods:

```
public static byte[] ToByteArray(this BitmapImage bitmapImage)
{
    byte[] bytes;
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        bitmapImage.BeginInit();
        bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        bitmapImage.StreamSource.CopyTo(ms);
        bitmapImage.EndInit();
        bytes = ms.ToArray();
    }
    return bytes;
}

public static BitmapImage ToBitmapImage(this byte[] bytes, int width, int height)
{
    BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
    {
        ms.Position = 0;
        bitmapImage.BeginInit();
        bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        bitmapImage.StreamSource = ms;
        bitmapImage.EndInit(); // HERE'S AN EXCEPTION!!!
    }
    return bitmapImage;
}
```

First one works fine, but when I try to convert from `byte[]` into `BitmapImage` I got a `NotSupportedException`... Why? How to correct the code of the 2nd method?

Comment: I just tested the code you posted and it worked fine for me.  Are you sure your bytes are a valid image?

Comment: `BitmapImage` should be valid, because I display it in my form:/ Don't know where the problem is...

Comment: I am having issues getting the ToByteArray method working, I keep getting errors stating that 'Cannot set the initializing state more than once.' on the BeginInit line.  I am wondering if something in that method is returning invalid bytes.

Comment: Refer to this link - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/e57f7731-c703-4c17-b1a2-32b155f9b745/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two problems with your `ToByteArray` method.

First it calls `BeginInit` and `EndInit` on an already initialized BitmapImage instance. This is not allowed, see the *Exceptions* list in [BeginInit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.begininit.aspx).

Second, the method could not be called on a BitmapImage that was created from an Uri instead of a Stream. Then the `StreamSource` property would be `null`.

I suggest to implement the method like shown below. This implementation would work for any BitmapSource, not only BitmapImages. And you are able to control the image format by selecting an appropriate [BitmapEncoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapencoder.aspx), e.g. `JpegBitmapEncoder` instead of `PngBitmapEncoder`.

```
public static byte[] ToByteArray(this BitmapSource bitmap)
{
    var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder(); // or any other encoder
    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmap));

    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        encoder.Save(ms);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

An image buffer returned by this `ToByteArray` method can always be converted back to a BitmapImage by your `ToBitmapImage` method.

And please note that the width and height arguments of your `ToBitmapImage` method are currently unused.

---

UPDATE

An alternative implementation of the decoding method could look like shown below, although it does not return a BitmapImage but only an instance of the base class BitmapSource. You may however change the return type to [BitmapFrame](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapframe.aspx).

```
public static BitmapSource ToBitmapImage(this byte[] bytes)
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
    {
        var decoder = BitmapDecoder.Create(stream, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
        return decoder.Frames[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your method `ToByteArray`, but still getting same error in my `ToBitmapImage` method. Do you know how do convert `byte[]` array into `BitmapImage` in the another way?

Comment: Your ToByteArray method looks ok. You may perhaps remove the `ms.Position = 0;` statement, since it is redundant. I have edited my answer to provide an alternative solution for decoding the image. Note however that this method will not return a BitmapImage but a BitmapFrame instead.

Comment: I guess, I can simply cast `BitmapSource` to `BitmapImage`?

Comment: No you can't. It's a BitmapFrame, not a BitmapImage. Both have BitmapSource as common base class but you can't cast one to the other. Why exactly do you need BitmapImage? BitmapSource usually provides all necessary information about the bitmap.

Comment: No I don't need `BitmapImage`. I just need 3 methods. The first one that renders my `System.Windows.Controls.Image` into `Bitmap/BitmapImage/etc.`, the second one that converts it into `byte[]` array (I need to serialize the image into binary file), and the third one that converts `byte[]` array back into my image (because I want to display it using binding for `System.Windows.Controls.Image`.

Comment: Ok, then you could give the alternative method it a try. You can directly assign the returned BitmapSource to the `Image.Source` property.